# Using 12 V 2A supply unit for higher amp value

Tags: capacitor, resistors

I recently purchased a Meanwell RS 25 12 which outputs 12V 2A and i want to use this to supply power to a blower fan. However, my blower fan requires 12V 8A. So what I want to do is to increase the power supply current such that I can conveniently power the blower fan. I know this can be achieved using full wave rectification but have little idea of the ratings of resistors and capacitors to employ. I can solder and can work with a good diagram if anyone can assist.

Comment: You bought a pushbike to tow a truck. It aint gonna happen.

Comment: But what if the pushbike is connected to the Internet of Things @Andyaka?

Comment: I think the humour part has just ended!

Comment: I think tou might want to check your sources, full wave rectification only converts an AC voltage to a chopped up DC voltage, it does nothing to increase the amount of power available, that'd be like getting 4x the horsepower out of a car engine by changing from a blue car to a red car.

Answer (score 5):

You can't create 12V 8A from a 12V 2A supply in any meaningfull way. Period.

The supply won't (safely) provide more than 12 * 2 = 24 Watt, and you require 12 * 8 = 104 Watt. If you could do this you would have solved the world's energy problem.

Comment: ... and all the physics laws would be invalidated and re-defined.